# How can I open or identify this lamp?

Tags: light-fixture

There's a lamp attached to the ceiling of the entrance to the garages of me and my neighbours, and its bulb needs to be replaced. The problem is: I have no idea how to open it.

There is no way to identify the manufacturer or model; it's simply not listed anywhere on the lamp itself and reverse image search doesn't give meaningful results. So finding a manual online is not an option right now.

There are caps with a small hole (less than 1cm) on both short sides of the lamp (best seen in the first picture); I suspect these should be able to move but I'm unable to make them do so.

[image]
[image]
[image]

(click on the pictures to enlarge them)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To me it looks like the white plastic end plates are removable, the cover may be screwed in place below those access plates.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my hunch; indeed I could remove them by wedging a precision screwdriver in the small cavity and applying a moderate amount of force sideways (away from the lamp). This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdLU5.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC5UT.jpg

Comment: In fact the pictures seem to show that the covers have been prised off before.  In general a slot that would take a typical electrical screwdriver (approx 3mm) is a good sign

Comment: The inner screw looks like it holds the cover on; the outer holds the entire assembly to to the ceiling/wall.

Comment: @CSM correct. I don't have a lot of DIY experience but once I see screws I'm confident I can disassemble and reassemble something without permanently breaking it. The bulb has been replaced meanwhile :)

Comment: I like that attitude, @Glorfindel!!